# Как сделать чтобы `this` указывал на себя в этих функциях?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.sossage')
        .mousedown(function (e) {
            offsetx = e.offsetX;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeState = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeState = false;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeState = false;
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            if (resizeState == true) {
                var widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $('.sossage').css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeState = false;
        });
```

Comment: 'var that = this' в том контесте исполнения который хотите перенести в функцию и 'this = that' в самой функции, чтобы контекст её исполнения был темже как и у "родителя". Если не очень понятно- отпиши- попробую нормальный пост накатать

Comment: @Den честно говоря не очень

Comment: В строках `var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));` `this` указывает именно на кликнутый елемент.
А елементов с классом `sossage` много. Моя проблема именно в том, чтобы работать с каждым отдельным елементом.

Comment: если выведеш в консоль после этой строки 'this' то получиш 1 div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mousemove работает со всеми элементами массива, а нужен только 1. Только проблема в том что как только курсор выходит за див скрипт багается т.к. e.target уже не див. Чуть переделал.

```js
var resizeState = false; 
var my_target;

$('.sossage')
        .mousedown(function (e) {
            offsetx = e.offsetX;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                my_target = e.target;
                resizeState = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeState = false;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeState = false;
                my_target = null;
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            if (resizeState == true) {
                var widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $(my_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeState = false;
        });
```

```css
.sossage {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sossage"></div>
<div class="sossage"></div>
<div class="sossage"></div>
<div class="sossage"></div>
<div class="sossage"></div>
<div class="sossage"></div>
```

Comment: Да, и ломает всю страницу)

Comment: переделал, проверь сейчас

Comment: Я окнончательно запутался. Теперь ресайз вообще не работает и в консоли пусто.

Comment: Работает. Но так как и прежде. Таскаются все дивы одновременно.

Comment: Проблема в другом. Я понял. Елементы друг друга толкают...

Comment: ну а куда им деватся, это ведь не модалы а просто дивы

Comment: С дивами разберусь. Спасибо. Еще вопрос есть. Тут подскажешь или писат новый?

Comment: напиши, тут ещё один эдитор делать как-то неочень

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30303/discussion-between-baga-and-den).